Can we exchange the order of derivative and integral with singularity?
Consider a two-variable real function $f(x,y)$ who has only one singularity point $(x_0,y_0)$ in the domain of definition with
$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}{\lim_{y \rightarrow y_0}}{f(x,y)} = C, \lim_{y \rightarrow y_0}{\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}}{f(x,y)} = 0$
where $C \neq 0$ is a finite value.
Now we are intersted in the term
$I = \frac{d}{dy} \int_{a}^{b}{f(x,y) dx}.$
where $x_0 \in [a,b]$
Can we exchange the order of derivative and integral here?
Can we get some formula like
$I = \frac{d}{dy} \int_{a}^{b}{f(x,y) dx} = \int_{a}^{b}{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y) dx} + c.t.?$
c.t. is a correction term.
For example, one can consider
$f(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}.$

What are we assuming about the behavior of $f$ away from $(x_0,y_0)$?

f away from (x0,y0) is assumed to be continuous and differentiable everywhere, i.e. (x0,y0) is the only singularity point.

This is only a partial answer: Let's focus on they $\frac{d}{dy}\int_a^b f(x,y)dx$ at point $y=y_0$.
Pick an open interval $I$ around $y_0$. Define $H$ by $$H(y)=\int_a^b  f(x,y)dx.$$  For each $y\in I\setminus \{ y_0\}$, define $$h_y(x)=\frac{f(x,y)-f(x, y_0)}{y-y^*}.$$  Note that for each $x_0\neq x\in [a,b]$, $$\lim_{y\to y_0}h_y(x)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}f(x, y_0).$$ Therefore $h_y\to \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}f(\cdot, y_0)$ almost surely.
Note also that for $y\neq y_0$, $$\frac{H(y)-H(y^*)}{y- y_0}=\int_a^b \frac{f(x,y)-f(x, y_0)}{y- y_0}dx=\int_a^b h_y(x)dx.$$
We have that $$\frac{d}{dy}\int_a^b f(x,y)dx\Bigr|_{y= y_0}=\lim_{y\to y_0}\frac{H(y)-H(y_0)}{y- y_0}=\lim_{y\to y_0}\int_a^b h_y(x)dx.$$
So the question amounts to: Since we know $h_y\to \frac{\partial f}{\partial}f(\cdot, y_0)$ almost surely, does $$\lim_{y\to y_0}\int_a^b h_y(x)dx=\int_a^b \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}f(x, y_0)dx?$$
I'm not aware of a way to give a complete answer to this question, but we can establish some sufficient conditions. The usual way is to use the dominated convergence theorem (or bounded convergence theorem). We would like a function $g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $y\in I\setminus \{ y_0\}$, $$\Bigl|\frac{f(x,y)-f(x, y_0)}{y- y_0}\Bigr|\leqslant g(x)$$ almost surely (which probably means we want it to hold for all $x\neq x_0$ in this case), and such that $$\int_a^b g(x)dx<\infty.$$ This may be something we can directly check, but it might also be easier to use the MVT. For $x\neq x_0$ and $y\in I\setminus\{y_0\}$, there exists $\xi_{x,y}$ in between $y$ and $y_0$ such that $$\frac{f(x,y)-f(x,y_0)}{y-y_0}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,\xi_{x,y}),$$ so $$\Bigl|\frac{f(x,y)-f(x,y_0)}{y-y_0}\Bigr|=\Bigl|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,\xi_{x,y})\Bigr|\leqslant \sup_{y\in I} \Bigl|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}f(x,y)\Bigr|.$$ Therefore we can define $$g(x)=\sup_{y\in I} \Bigl|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}f(x,y)\Bigr|$$ and attempt to check whether $\int_a^b g(x)dx$ is finite.
